# How to install Warty Warthog on VirtualBox?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, virtualbox, lvm

I was following this [tutorial on how to install Ubuntu 4.10](http://onubuntu.blogspot.in/2011/08/from-warty-to-oneiric-installing-ubuntu.html)

But in the step for partitioning disks, I only get the option:

```
Manually edit partition table
```

When I try to create a new logical volume group it shows the following
[image: Partition disks screen]
[image]

Also I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager)

but I got the following results
[image: Error output]
[image: fdisk -l output]

Are there special versions of **Warty Warthog** for Oracle VirtualBox?

[Note: I need to install Warty Warthog as I have to give demo of exploits on Old Linux Systems as a part of our Project]

Comment: Do you need to add a logical volume for any specific reason, are the defaults not good enough?

Comment: @Shutupsquare The problem was that I had the disk in SATA which was not being detected as in images... Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: ahh okay, I think we both figured it out at the same time.

Comment: PS I had to disable mouse pointer integration once it was installed as mouse cursor was crazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay so I tried and got the same problem.

You can get round it by using a IDE controller based HDD rather than a SATA ( which is default )

Edit your `VM -> Settings -> Storage`, then add a HDD to the **IDE controller** and delete the SATA controller.

Reboot the it should work okay.

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit the question so that others who find this question can see the images and links???

Comment: Sure, will do it now.